# Sich entwickeln oder sich entfalten

Tags: difference, word-choice, synonym

> **sich entwickeln:**
> 1. allmählich entstehen, sich stufenweise herausbilden
>       2a. (von Lebewesen, Pflanzen) ein Stadium erreichen, in dem vorhandene Anlagen zur [vollen] Entfaltung kommen
>       2b. in einem Prozess fortlaufend in eine neue [bessere] Phase treten
>       3a. durch seine Einwirkung auf ein höheres Niveau heben
>       3b. allmählich unter bestimmten Bedingungen zu etwas anderem, Neuem werden
>       4a. bei einem Prozess, Vorgang durch sich oder an sich entstehen lassen
>       4b. bei etwas wirksam werden lassen, als Fähigkeit aus sich hervorbringen oder in Erscheinung treten lassen
>       4c. in einem Arbeitsprozess etwas Neues, Fortschrittlicheres erfinden, konstruieren
>       5. in allen Einzelheiten darlegen, jemandem auseinandersetzen
>
> **sich entfalten:** 
>      1a. (etwas Gefaltetes) ausbreiten, auseinanderfalten
>      1b. sich öffnen, sich auseinanderfalten
>      2a. sich [voll] entwickeln
>      2b. zeigen, zur Geltung bringen, an den Tag legen

Quelle: Duden

Die Bedeutungen überschneiden sich. Gibt es denn einen Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern in diesen Bereich?

Comment: Ja, der Unterschied ist da, wo sie sich nicht überschneiden.

Comment: Eine bessere Antwort als die, die Robert gegeben hat, kann man kaum geben, vor allem wo doch alle möglichen Bedeutungen ohnehin schon in der Frage selbst aufgelistet sind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sich entwickelt** bezeichnet einen Prozess der Modifikation, wenn man so möchte. Aber man kann sich dem Begriff besser über Beispiele nähern:

> Der ins rollen geratene Stein *entwickelte sich* zu einer Lawine. (Stein → Lawine)
>
> Der Hurrikan schwächte sich ab und *entwickelte sich* zu einem normalen Tiefdruckgebiet. (Hurrikan → Tief)
>
> Über Millionen von Jahren *entwickelte sich* die Distel zu ihrer heutigen Gestalt. (unbekannter Vorläufer → Distel)
>
> In zehn Minuten Diskussion *entwickelte sich* die Lösung aus Hans’ Vorschlag. (Vorschlag → Lösung)
>
> Ich *entwickele mich* noch zu einem professionellen Schauspieler. (unbekannter jetziger Status → Schauspieler)
>
> [Bisasam](http://pokewiki.de/Bisasam) *entwickelte sich* zu [Bisaknosp](http://pokewiki.de/Bisaknosp)! (klar, oder?)

Wie man an den verschiedenen Beispielen sieht, ist das Entwickeln nicht an eine bestimmte Zeitspanne gebunden: Die Entwicklung des Pokémons läuft binnen Sekunden ab, die der Distel über Millionen von Jahren. Auch muss das Ergebnis nicht größer, stärker oder besser sein: Das Tiefdruckgebiet ist schwächer als der Hurrikan.

---

**Sich entfalten** bezeichnet, neben dem wörtlichen Ausklappen aus einem zusammengefalteten Zustand (Blüten aus Knospen oder ein Papier entknittern und glätten), einen wesentlich enger und anders gefassten Begriff: Es geht darum, dass man sich eingeschränkt gefühlt hat (oder haben könnte) und nun diese Einschränkungen fallenlassen kann.

> Nach Ende der Naziherrschaft konnten *sich* querdenkende Personen endlich wieder frei *entfalten*.
>
> Ein Künstler strebt an, seine künstlerischen Fähigkeiten – und damit auch *sich* – voll zu *entfalten*.

Die *Entfaltung* ist also das breitmachen aus einem eingeengten Zustand, während die *Entwicklung* nur ganz allgemein den Übergang von einem Zustand zu einem anderen beschreibt.

Answer (score 1):

*Sich entwickeln*: tut man immer, gut oder schlecht (roughly: *develop*)
*Sich entfalten*: benutzt man wenn man sich besonders gut entwickelt (roughly: *unfold*)

> Durch das Umfeld entwickeln sich Kriminelle.
>   Durch das Malen entfaltet sich die Seele.

Entfalten hat also ein wenig auch einen künstlerischen Bezug, muss es aber nicht.

Comment: Die Zeichensetzung zieht den Post herunter.